# Pop-up window won't open when using tablet (Pure CSS)

Tags: html, css, popup, modal-dialog, tablet

My site has a pop-up which acts like a modal but isn't a modal, and it drops into view when a user clicks this link/label

```
 <a class="loginbtn"><label class="loginbin" for="lightbox-two">LOGIN</label></a>
```

It works fine on my PC and mobile, but not on my tablet (Samsung Galaxy Tab GT p7500R). The popup uses pure CSS to function, and I've provided a [fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/erbea2g1/2/)
Simply click "Login" and a window drops down. Perhaps there is something in the CSS preventing it from working on tablets (or maybe only mine). Do you know the problem? Thank you

**Reference HTML**

```
<a class="loginbtn"><label class="loginbin" for="lightbox-two">LOGIN</label></a>
<aside class="lightbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="state" id="lightbox-two" />
    <article class="content">
        <form id="loginform" name="loginform" method="POST" class="login" action="#">
            <input name="emailaddy" id="emailaddy" type="email" class="feedback-input" placeholder="My Email"/>
            <div id="formResponse" style="display: none;"></div>
            <button type="submit" name="loginsubmit" class="loginbutton">Login</button>
        </form>
    </article>
    <label class="backdrop" for="lightbox-two"></label>
</aside>
```

**CSS**

```
.state{position:absolute;top:0;left:-100vw}
.state:checked ~ .content{-webkit-transform:none;-ms-transform:none;transform:none;margin-top: 10%;overflow:auto; border-radius: 9px;  background-color: black;}
.state:checked ~ .backdrop{bottom:0;opacity:1;z-index:1}
.lightbox{position:fixed;top:0;right:0;left:0;height:0;padding:0 20px}
.lightbox .content{display:-webkit-box;display:-webkit-flex;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;-webkit-box-orient:vertical;-webkit-box-direction:normal;-webkit-flex-direction:column;-ms-flex-direction:column;flex-direction:column;overflow:hidden;position:relative;z-index:2;max-width:500px;max-height:95vh;margin:20px auto;padding:20px;background:#fff;-webkit-transform:translateY(-200%);-ms-transform:translateY(-200%);transform:translateY(-200%);-webkit-transition:.3s -webkit-transform ease-in-out;transition:.3s transform ease-in-out;border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1)}
.lightbox .header,.lightbox .footer{display:-webkit-box;display:-webkit-flex;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;-webkit-flex-shrink:0;-ms-flex-negative:0;flex-shrink:0;-webkit-box-align:center;-webkit-align-items:center;-ms-flex-align:center;align-items:center}
.lightbox .header .h,.lightbox .footer .h{margin:0}
.lightbox .header .button:not(:first-child),.lightbox .footer .button:not(:first-child){margin-left:auto}
.lightbox .header{padding-bottom:10px}
.lightbox .footer{padding-top:20px}
.lightbox .main{-webkit-box-flex:1;-webkit-flex-grow:1;-ms-flex-positive:1;flex-grow:1}
.lightbox .backdrop{position:fixed;z-index:-1;top:0;right:0;bottom:100%;left:0;opacity:0;background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);-webkit-transition:.3s opacity ease-in-out;transition:.3s opacity ease-in-out}
```

Comment: Any ideas? This is driving me nuts!